# Extract needed key values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks for looking.
So basically I have an array of objects. Which are updating. So there more tasks added dynamically.

```
let tasks = [
    {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "Create smth else", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "do smth", assignee: 'Adam'},
    {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'},
    {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'}
 ]
```

What I want is to create some dynamically updated statistics from it.
Something like this.
Assingnee - Done Tasks
Adam            1
Ann             2
John            3
...            ...
How can I iterate through the array and extract needed info???

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Your result example is sorted from least assigned tasks to most assigned tasks. Does the result have to be sorted?

Comment: @Thijs, it could be sorted by the name as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz, good point. I've updated my answer so the resulting array can be sorted on assignee or number of assigned tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this the right way:

```js
let tasks = [{title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'}, {title: "Create smth else", assignee: 'John'}, {title: "do smth", assignee: 'Adam'}, {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'}, {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'}, {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'}];

let result = {};

tasks.forEach(t => {                              // For each entry in your array, 
    result[t.assignee] = result[t.assignee] || 0; // Set a default value, we haven't seen this assignee yet.
    result[t.assignee]++;                         // Increment for assignee
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result I first create a map to sum up the number of tasks per assignee. Next I convert the map back to an array where each item is an object with the assignee name and the number of assigned tasks. After this is done the result is an array which can be sorted on either assignee or number of assigned tasks.

```js
const 
  tasks = [
      {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
      {title: "Create smth else", assignee: 'John'},
      {title: "do smth", assignee: 'Adam'},
      {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'},
      {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
      {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'},
      {title: "Additional task", assignee: "Becky"}
  ];
  
  
function transformData(inputArray) {
  const
   tasksMap = new Map();
   
  // Iterate over all tasks...
  inputArray.forEach(task => {
    // Check if the map has a value for the current name.
    if (!tasksMap.has(task.assignee)) {
      // The key doesn't exist yet, create it by assigning 1 to it.
      tasksMap.set(task.assignee, 1);
    } else {
      // The name is already in the map, increase the task count by 1.
      tasksMap.set(task.assignee, tasksMap.get(task.assignee) + 1);
    }
  });
  
  const
    tasksArray = [];
  
  // Iterate over all the items in the map and convert each entry to an 
  // object and place it in the array.
  tasksMap.forEach((value, key) => tasksArray.push({
    assignee: key,
    tasks: value
  }));
  
  return tasksArray;
}
 
  
  
  
/* === SORT METHODS === */
function sortByName(a, b) {
  if (a.assignee < b.assignee) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.assignee > b.assignee) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

function sortByTasks(a, b) {
  return a.tasks - b.tasks;
}



/* === UI METHODS === */
function arrayToUI(sourceArray, element) {
  element.innerHTML = `<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Assignee</th><th>Tasks</th></tr></thead> 
  <tbody>
    ${sourceArray.reduce((html, item) => { 
      html += `<tr><td>${item.assignee}</td><td>${item.tasks}</td></tr>`;
      return html;
    }, '')}
  </tbody>
  </table>`;
}

const
  tasksArray = transformData(tasks);
  
arrayToUI(tasksArray, document.getElementById('output-original'));

tasksArray.sort(sortByName);
arrayToUI(tasksArray, document.getElementById('output-assignee'));

tasksArray.sort(sortByTasks);
arrayToUI(tasksArray, document.getElementById('output-tasks'));
```

```html
<p>Output after summing up tasks:</p>
<div id="output-original"></div>

<p>Output after sorting by assignee:</p>
<div id="output-assignee"></div>

<p>Output after sorting by tasks:</p>
<div id="output-tasks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Array.reduce

### Resource:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

### Example:

This can be written shorter but this is better readable.

```js
let tasks = [
    {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "Create smth else", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "do smth", assignee: 'Adam'},
    {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'},
    {title: "Create smth", assignee: 'John'},
    {title: "Create more smth", assignee: 'Ann'}
 ]

var result = tasks.reduce(function(total, task){  

 var obj = total;
 if(total.title)
 {
     obj = {};
  obj[total.assignee] = 1;
 }

if(!obj[task.assignee]){
    obj[task.assignee] = 1;  
}
else
{
    obj[task.assignee] = obj[task.assignee] + 1;
}
return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ___Please___ refrain from using w3schools. Their examples are often incomplete, misleading or simply incorrect. Their attempt to imply a relation to w3c is also rather misleading. Use sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

Comment: It doesn't work properly, it reports John has 2 tasks instead of 3. Send an empty object into the reduce as the initial value and drop the `if(total.title)` condition.

Comment: I rewrote some code before changing the example. Fixed it now. I do believe w3schools to be a good source for quickly grasping the simple concepts of a method. You may disagree offcourse.

Comment: Let's put it this way, w3schools is the only (major) documentation out there that has a site like http://www.w3fools.com/ . Now, as they say, w3schools has improved a bit, but it's still inferior to other sites out there by a significant margin.